# Replicating code 30+ times with slight differences?

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if it is possible to replicate my code 30 times with slight variations to FIND function, finding different items "New Food Price, New Pizza Price, New Seafood Price.. Etc" 
If I was to copy the whole code 34 times it would be extremely long, and if anything changed I would have to change it 34 times. Is it at all possible to repeat majority of the code 34 times and just change the FIND word & Formulas that are pasted?

```
Dim rng As Range
  Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("A1:FF1")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="US", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        LastColumn = rFind.Column
    End If
End With
Set rng = Range(Cells(2, LastColumn), Cells(2, LastColumn + 7))
final_Column = Application.Match("New Food Price", rng, 0)
LastColumn = LastColumn + final_Column
Columns(LastColumn).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, LastColumn).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "New Food Price"
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    Range(Cells(3, (LastColumn)), Cells(LR, (LastColumn))).Formula = "=(5)"
    LastColumn = LastColumn + 1
    Columns(LastColumn).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, LastColumn).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Difference"
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    Range(Cells(3, (LastColumn)), Cells(LR, (LastColumn))).Formula = "=(6)"


Set rng = Range(Cells(2, LastColumn), Cells(2, LastColumn + 7))
final_Column2 = Application.Match("New Wine Price", rng, 0)
LastColumn = LastColumn + final_Column2
Columns(LastColumn).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, LastColumn).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "New Wine Price"
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    Range(Cells(3, (LastColumn)), Cells(LR, (LastColumn))).Formula = "=(5)"
    LastColumn = LastColumn + 1
    Columns(LastColumn).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, LastColumn).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Difference"
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    Range(Cells(3, (LastColumn)), Cells(LR, (LastColumn))).Formula = "=(6)"
```

Comment: And that's what a loop is for :). Place all your FIND values in an array and iterate through that.

Comment: Create an array containing the different values you'll be looking for `MyArray = Array("New Food Price", "New Wine Price")`, and then loop through the array `For i = LBound(MyArray) to UBound(MyArray)` performing your operations and substituting the hard coded values with your current array value `MyArray(i)`.  Give it a try and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi Tigeravatar - I was able to get that to work! I am now stuck on something slightly more difficult and cannot figure out any work arounds. I am trying to do a vlookup based on my array. For example if MyArray is "New Food", I am trying to do a vlookup with col_Index_Number based on "Food Type" from a different workbook. If MyArray is "Price", I am trying to do a vlookup with col_Index_Number based on "Price" from a different workbook... do you know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
Sub SearchAll()
    Dim SearchTerms As Variant
    SearchTerms = Array("US", "UK", "BR")

    For Each SearchTerm In SearchTerms
        Search SearchTerm
    Next

End Sub

Sub Search(SearchTerm)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("A1:FF1")
        Set rFind = .Find(What:=SearchTerm, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            LastColumn = rFind.Column
        End If
    End With
    ...
    ...
End Sub
```

And a short explanation, as requested:

The first Sub creates an array of search terms. It is then stepped through, using a For Each. For each value the Search method is called with one parameter. This parameter is then used in the Find call.

Comment: A little explanation would be nice to go along.